# UndefinedDocblockClass psalm error when using a trait to mark magic properties as deprecated

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc, psalm-php

I'm trying to use PhpDoc to hint all the deprecated magic properties set on a Laravel Model using the [mixin described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554329/how-to-deprecate-phps-magic-property-in-phpdoc).

I am using JetBrains PhpStorm 2022.1.1, PHP 8.1.6 and Psalm 4.23.0

I have a trait, defined in `app/Models/Traits/PhpDoc/ProductPhpDocTrait.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits\PhpDoc;

/**
 * @property int id
 * @property int type
*/
trait ProductPhpDocTrait
{

    /**
     * @deprecated
     * @var string $display_status ;
     */
    public string $display_status;

}
```

And I'm using this trait on my model in `app/Models/Product.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

/**
 * @mixin App\Models\Traits\PhpDoc\ProductPhpDocTrait
 */
class Product extends Model implements HasLinkableTexts
{
    //...
}
```

Autocomplete is now working for the properties documented in the trait, and those which are deprecated are now marked with strikethrough.

But Psalm is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR: UndefinedDocblockClass - app/Models/Product.php:21:7 - Docblock-defined class, interface or enum named App\Models\Traits\PhpDoc\ProductPhpDocTrait does not exist (see https://psalm.dev/200)
class Product extends Model implements HasLinkableTexts
```

(the line & character reference the opening `class` definition)

It seems that the namespace is fine up until two levels above where the file resides:

[image: Image showing PhpStorm issues]

If I move the trait up a level (in the filesystem and the namespace) to `app/Models/Traits/ProductPhpDocTrait.php`, PhpStorm still flags the error as two levels up the namespace:

[image]

If I move the trait into the Models folder (and update the namespace), I still get the same Psalm error that the trait does not exist.

How can I resolve this, such that I can hint deprecated magic properties with the code passing static analysis?

Comment: Since the namespace is already `App\Models`, it makes sense to try using either `Traits\PhpDoc\ProductPhpDocTrait` or `\App\Models\Traits\PhpDoc\ProductPhpDocTrait`.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneMorozov - neither of those worked though. I've tried letting PhpStorm add the use statement using the 'import' context action too, but no joy.

Comment: `class, interface or enum` - looks like Psalm does not expect a trait there. Have you tried converting the trait to a class instead?