# How to document a Laravel model attribute as deprecated?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, laravel-10, php-8.2

I have an eloquent model in Laravel that I would like to mark an `user_id` attribute as deprecated using the `@deprectated` tag in PHPDoc.

I can add the `@property` tag to my model to document `user_id` but if I try to add the deprecated tag my IDE (vscode) still does not inform me that the attribute is deprecated.

Looking at the documentation I can't see any way of combining both @property and @deprecated.

Does anyone know a way for me to document this correctly?

**The model**

```
/**
 * App\Task\Models\Task
 *
 * @property null|int $user_id
 */
final class Task extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'int',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
    ];

}
```

**Attempted Code**

`@property @deprecated null|int $user_id`

**Versions**

- Laravel: 10
- PHP: 8.2
- VSCode: 1.80.2
- VSCode extension PHP Intelephense: 1.9.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deprecate PHP's magic property in PHPDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554329/how-to-deprecate-phps-magic-property-in-phpdoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different attributes. So you can't declare it in one line.

```
/**
 * App\Task\Models\Task
 *
 * @property null|int $user_id
 * @deprecated @property null|int $user_id This property will be removed.
 */
final class Task extends Model

}
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that you are now deprecating the whole class